# Basic algebra word problem

Tags: word-problem

Alaska is a logician who also likes to impress people with his use of simple logic to do “magic tricks”. He is practicing his next big trick. He asks his friend to think of two numbers, write them on pieces of paper and throw them into a bag. Meanwhile, Alaska also thinks of a number and drops it into the bag. He then waves his wand and a glittery paper comes out of the bag. The numbers his friend picked are both less than the number Alaska dropped into the bag. The first number is 40 percent less than Alaska’s number, while the second number is 50 percent less than the same. The glittery paper has the percentage comparison of the two numbers from his friend. What is the percentage on the glittery paper?

Comment: A start: if $x$ is Alaska's number, the other two numbers are $0.6x$ and $0.5x$.

Comment: That’s what I did too, but the answer given is 20

Comment: Well, one is 20 percent larger than the other. Perhaps that is what the vague term "percentage comparison" means.

Comment: Ah yes makes sense now